# Java Unicode variable names

Tags: java, variables, unicode

I got into an interesting discussion in a forum where we discussed the naming of variables.

Conventions aside, I noticed that it is legal for a variable to have the name of a Unicode character. For example, the following is legal:

```
int \u1234;
```

However, if I for example gave it the name #, it produces an error. According to [Sun's tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), it is valid if *"beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_"."*

But the [Unicode 1234](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=4640&number=128) is some Ethiopian character. So what is really defined as a "letter"?

Comment: I got here because I was writing a table of scenarios for a test and I wanted to use enum constants with names like `AUTH_✅` and `AUTH_❌` so everything lined up nicely and it was easy to read at a glance. I was actually surprised to learn that these types of characters weren't allowed in identifiers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Unicode standard defines what counts as a letter.

From the [Java Language Specification, section 3.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8):

> Letters and digits may be drawn from
>   the entire Unicode character set,
>   which supports most writing scripts in
>   use in the world today, including the
>   large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and
>   Korean. This allows programmers to use
>   identifiers in their programs that are
>   written in their native languages.
>
> A
>   "Java letter" is a character for which
>   the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)
>   returns true. A "Java letter-or-digit"
>   is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)
>   returns true.

From the `Character` documenation for `isJavaIdentifierPart`:

> Determines if the character (Unicode code point) may be part of a Java identifier as other 
>   than the first character.
>   A character may be part of a Java identifier if any of the following are true:
>
> - it is a letter
> - it is a currency symbol (such as '$')
> - it is a connecting punctuation character (such as '_')
> - it is a digit
> - it is a numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
> - it is a combining mark
> - it is a non-spacing mark
> - isIdentifierIgnorable(codePoint) returns true for the character

Answer (score 8):

Unicode characters fall into character classes. There's a set of Unicode characters which fall into the class "letter".

Determined by `Character.isLetter(c)` for Java. But for identifiers, `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c)` and `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c)` are more relevant.

For the relevant Unicode spec, see [this](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UCD.html#ID_Start).

Comment: I found this answer succinct and exactly what I wanted. The other answer has what I am looking for too, but so much stuff in it that I noticed this answer first.