# How to check if the class name is valid?

Tags: java, class, methods

Is there a method in Java to check if a string can be used as a class name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression matching fully qualified java classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205339/regular-expression-matching-fully-qualified-java-classes)

Comment: He's asking if the name would be a legal name, not if the class actually exists.  (I think)

Comment: yes i want to create a new class with reflection and the name... so i have to check if the name is valid

Comment: then it sounds like you do want to know if the string refers to a valid class.  See answers below.  I thought you were checking for whether the name follows the rules of how classes are allowed to be named.

Comment: Sorry.. first i create a new java file and then i create a new object with reflection... so you are right, with your first post

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205339/regular-expression-matching-fully-qualified-java-classes as the poster doesn't care if the solution is regular expression or not

Answer (score 29):

[`SourceVersion.isName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isName-java.lang.CharSequence-) can be used to check fully qualified names.

If no `.`s should be allowed, the check can be done this way:

```
boolean isValidName (String className) {
    return SourceVersion.isIdentifier(className) && !SourceVersion.isKeyword(className);
}
```

Comment: You're three years late to the party, but this is precisely the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, with the `Class.forName(String name)` method, which can be used to test this as follows:

```
public static boolean classExists(String className)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(className);
        return true;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit: If, as dashrb said, you're asking for a way to determine if a String can be used as a class name (rather than if there already is a class by that name), then what you need is a combination of the method I posted above (with the booleans flipped, as you can't reuse class names), and in combination with a check to see if the String is a Java-reserved keyword. I had a similar problem recently and made a utility class for it which you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/mnSKG12g). I won't write it for you, but you basically just need to add in a check for `!JavaKeywords.isKeyword(className)`.

Edit 2: And of course, if you want to also enforce generally accepted coding standards, you could just make sure that the class name starts with a capital letter with:

```
return Character.isUpperCase(className.charAt(0));
```

**Edit 3**: As Ted Hopp points out, even containing a java keyword invalidates a class name, and as JavaKeywords is used in one of my production applications, I have made an [updated version](http://pastebin.com/E1bih2Aw) which includes the method `containsKeyword(String toCheck)` which will also check for this eventuality. The method is as follows (please note you need the list of keywords in the class too):

```
public static boolean containsKeyword(String toCheck)
{
    toCheck = toCheck.toLowerCase();
    for(String keyword : keywords)
    {
        if(toCheck.equals(keyword) || toCheck.endsWith("." + keyword) ||
           toCheck.startsWith(keyword + ".") || toCheck.contains("." + keyword + "."))
        {
            return true;
        }//End if
    }//End for
    return false;
}//End containsKeyword()
```

Comment: You don't need to have you first letter to be capital.

Comment: @tcb I know, but it's fairly standard practise to have classes start with a capital letter, which I'm fairly sure every non-primitive class in the built-in packages does.

Comment: This deals only with simple names. But a qualified name like `com.example.Foo` is a legal class name.

Comment: See @fabian's answer for a belated but vastly superior solution.  Let Java's own SourceVersion class tell you whether the String is a valid name, including whether it is a keyword.

Answer (score 5):

I used the list of java keywords kindly offered by MrLore.

```
private static final Set<String> javaKeywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "abstract",     "assert",        "boolean",      "break",           "byte",
    "case",         "catch",         "char",         "class",           "const",
    "continue",     "default",       "do",           "double",          "else",
    "enum",         "extends",       "false",        "final",           "finally",
    "float",        "for",           "goto",         "if",              "implements",
    "import",       "instanceof",    "int",          "interface",       "long",
    "native",       "new",           "null",         "package",         "private",
    "protected",    "public",        "return",       "short",           "static",
    "strictfp",     "super",         "switch",       "synchronized",    "this",
    "throw",        "throws",        "transient",    "true",            "try",
    "void",         "volatile",      "while"
));

private static final Pattern JAVA_CLASS_NAME_PART_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z_$]+[a-zA-Z0-9_$]*");

public static boolean isJavaClassName(String text) {
    for (String part : text.split("\\.")) {
        if (javaKeywords.contains(part) ||
                !JAVA_CLASS_NAME_PART_PATTERN.matcher(part).matches()) {
            return false;
        }           
    }
    return text.length() > 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't deal properly with names like `"com.example.true` (which is an illegal name because one _component_ of the name is a keyword). Note that the test also needs to allow names like `"com.example.true_fact"`.

Comment: Not quite fixed. It still will allow names like `"com.example.true"`.

Comment: Hope it's fine now. Nice pair programming :)

Comment: See @fabian's answer for a belated but vastly superior solution.  Let Java's own SourceVersion class tell you whether the String is a valid name, including whether it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

yap -

```
Class.forName(String className);
```

It returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.
And throws `Exceptions`

```
LinkageError - if the linkage fails
ExceptionInInitializerError - if the initialization provoked by this method fails
ClassNotFoundException - if the class cannot be located
```

Comment: This checks whether the class exists, not whether the string is legal for use as a class name (which is what OP wants to know).

Comment: @Ted I have just give info and I think it would be enough info to make a function like MrLore suggested.

Comment: I must disagree. OP wants to know if a name would be valid as a class name, not whether a class exists. The problem with your suggestion is that it will throw the same `ClassNotFoundException` for legal names like `"foo.bar"` (if the class does not exist) and for illegal names like `"!=?"`.