# Regex to match valid Java path identifier

Tags: regex

Suppose that `*a*` is a Java identifier. I would like a regex to match things like this:

`\#a`
`\#a.a.a` (*a* any number of times)

but not this:

`\#a.` (ending with dot)

So in a phase like this: **"#a.a less than #a."** it would match only the first `\#a.a` (because it doesn't end with a dot).

This regex:

`\#[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*(\\.[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*)*`

almost does the job, but it matches the last case too.

Thank you.

Marcos

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205339/regular-expression-matching-fully-qualified-class-names

Comment: Although most Java identifiers use Ascii, all UTF-8 characters are allowed, so it's better to use \p{L} instead of a-zA-Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right but some minor adjustments are needed. Consider this regex:

```
#[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*(?:\.[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*)*(?!\w*\.)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/kJbSJKHhtv

Translated to Java:

```
(?i)#[a-z_$][\\w$]*(?:\\.[a-z_$][\\w$]*)*(?!\\w*\\.)
```

Comment: With this statement "#a.a less than #var and #a.aaa." it still matches #a.aa I would like it to ignore the last #a.aaa. completely.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with a negated look ahead.  This first looks for "#text_$".  It then looks for ".text_$" or more times. The match will be invalid if it ends with 0 or more of "text_$" and a period.  This is assuming the `i` modifier is on.

At first I just had it as checking if it didn't end with a period, but that would just take away the last character in the match.

```
\\#([a-z_$][a-z_$\d]*)(\.[a-z_$][a-z_$\d]*)*(?![a-z_$\d]*\.)
```

### Results

```
\#abc           => YES
\#abc.abc       => YES
\#abc.a23.abc   => YES
\#abc.abc.abc.  => NO
\#abc.2bc.abc   => NO
```

[Try it out](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/dmg4rqq1)

Comment: @Marcos: added digits.  The accepted answer also did not work for digits.

Comment: The complete regex that I'm using is this: (?i)#[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*(?:\\.[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*)*(?!\\w*\\.) So it works with digits.

Comment: @DanielGimenez: My answer definitely works with digits, you can try yourself.

Comment: @anubhava you're right.  I suppose our answers are redudant because at the end I reached the same answer you had without the `\w`.  I will delete in a few after I know you read this comment.

Comment: @DanielGimenez: Yes at this point I would think both answers look same (after you start using `\w`). But I would say just leave it like this, why delete.