# How to strip the package name from a fully qualified class name

Tags: java, regex

How to match a fully qualified class name like `com.mycompany.models.Friend` using regex and strip away the package name so the result would be `Friend` for the example given?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205339/regular-expression-matching-fully-qualified-java-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
```

This will print `Friend`

Comment: The OP want a regex to extract Friend from any fully qualified name, and this just a simple way with out using regex, and am pretty sure that this can solved the OP problem

Comment: I adjusted the question and the title to be less ambiguous. I undid my down vote. Sorry for that.

Comment: I got 2 downvoted also, i don't know why, but Its Just ok.

Comment: @Harmlezz it seems that OP wants to first match full package name of class from its text and then find name of class. So your edit could oversimplify what OP really wanted.

Comment: @Pshemo I hope I improved things now to catch both aspects.

Comment: @Harmlezz Now should be better. I suspect that all here got downvoted because initially we didn't try to find full package name of class but we assumed that it was passed as input.