# How to determine if a string is English sentence or code?

Tags: java, string, nlp

Consider the following two strings, the first one is code, the second one is English sentence (phrase to be precise). How can I detect that the first one is code and the second is not.

```
1. for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
2. do something in English (not necessary to be a sentence).
```

I'm thinking about counting special characters (such as "=", ";", "++", etc ), and set if to some threshold.  Are there any better ways to do this? Any Java libraries?

Note that the code may not parsable, because it is not a complete method/statement/expression.

My assumption is that English sentences are pretty regular, it most likely contains only ",", ".", "_", "(", ")", etc. They do not contains something like this: `write("the whole lot of text");`

Comment: My, that will be difficult, to be honest, I would do some research on that and bring it here after you have some code

Comment: I'm seeking some shortcut solutions.

Comment: True, but we are programmers, not brainstormers. We can't help you with coming up with ideas, especially if it's as open-ended as this one... Come back with code and then we'll be able to help you

Comment: You need to state your assumptions. In general it's not possible. Just consider a book of math problems or `write("the whole lot of text");` type of code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I only care about Java code.

Comment: You could try and compile or evaluate it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The code is not complete, so not parsable.

Comment: I believe you would need to do a bit more then solve the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). I wish you luck! You might be able to *cheat* can you manually tag the literals with something like `"text:"`

Comment: Is the code guaranteed to be Java code?  Some languages will have code that is also valid English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_(programming_language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to convert the string to a set to tokens. For example, the code line above may become "KEY,SEPARATOR,ID,ASSIGN,NUMBER,SEPARATOR,...". And then we can use simple rules to separate code from English.

[check out the code here](http://www.programcreek.com/2015/01/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-english-or-java-code/)

Answer (score 5):

You can try the OpenNLP sentence parser. It returns the n best parses for a sentence. For most English sentences it returns at least one. I believe, that for most code snippets it won't return any and hence you can be quite sure it is not an English sentence.

Use this code for parsing:

```
    // Initialize the sentence detector
    final SentenceDetectorME sdetector = EasyParserUtils
            .getOpenNLPSentDetector(Constants.SENTENCE_DETECTOR_DATA);

    // Initialize the parser
    final Parser parser = EasyParserUtils
            .getOpenNLPParser(Constants.PARSER_DATA_LOC);

    // Get sentences of the text
    final String sentences[] = sdetector.sentDetect(essay);

    // Go through the sentences and parse each
    for (final String sentence : sentences) {
        // Parse the sentence, produce only 1 parse
        final Parse[] parses = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 10);
        if (parses.length == 0) {
            // Most probably this is code
        }
        else {
            // An English sentence
        }
    }
```

and these are the two helper methods (from EasyParserUtils) used in the code:

```
public static Parser getOpenNLPParser(final String parserDataURL) {
    try (final InputStream isParser = new FileInputStream(parserDataURL);) {
        // Get model for the parser and initialize it
        final ParserModel parserModel = new ParserModel(isParser);
        return ParserFactory.create(parserModel);
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public static SentenceDetectorME getOpenNLPSentDetector(
        final String sentDetDataURL) {
    try (final InputStream isSent = new FileInputStream(sentDetDataURL)) {
        // Get models for sentence detector and initialize it
        final SentenceModel sentDetModel = new SentenceModel(isSent);
        return new SentenceDetectorME(sentDetModel);
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look into *lexical analysis* and *parsing* (same as if you were writing a compiler). You might not even need a parser if you're not requiring full statements.

Comment: You answer gave me some hint, I have some idea now. +!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Java parser or create one using the [BNF](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/BNFindex.html) but the issue here is that you said the code may not be parsable so it will fail.

My advice : use some custom regexp to detect special patterns in the code. Use as many as possible to have a good success rate.

Some examples :

- `for\s*\(` (for loop)
- `while\s*\(` (while loop)
- `[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*\s*\(` ([constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205467/2003986))
- `\)\s*\{` (begin of a block / method)
- ...

Yes it's a long shot but looking at what you want, you don't have many possibility.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel, Compilers already do this for you. The first stage of any compiling process checks if the tokens in the file are within language scope. This certainly won't help us since English and java don't diff in that. However the second stage, the syntatic analysis, will print a error with any English formed sentence instead of java code (or anything else that isn't proper java). So instead of using external libraries and try to use an alternative approach, why don't you use the already available java compiler?

you can have a wrapper class such as

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(){

         /*Insert code to check here*/

    }

}
```

that gets compiled and if it goes well then bum, you know it's valid code. Of course it won't work with snippets of code which aren't complete such as that for loop you put in the example without an ending bracket. If it doesn't compile well, you can threat the string in may ways, such as trying to parse it with your own homebrew pseudo-english syntatic analyzer made with flex-bison, the tools of GNU used to make GCC for example. I don't know exactly what are you trying to accomplish with the program you are trying to make, but this way you can know if it's code, a handcrafted english sentece, or just rubbish you shouldn't care. Parsing natural languages is really hard and for now modern approaches use  inaccurate statitiscal methods, so they are not always right, something you might not want in your program.

Comment: This assumes that code is not a full class. It also assumes that there will be no programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple method that seems to work pretty well on some samples. Take out the `System.out`. It is for illustrative purposes only. As you can see from the sample output, code comments look like text, so if large non-javadoc block comments are mixed into the code you might get false positives. The hard-coded thresholds are my estimation. Feel free to fine-tune them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String arg : args){
        System.out.println(arg);
        System.out.println(codeStatus(arg));
    }
}

static CodeStatus codeStatus (String string) {
    String[] words = string.split("\\b");
    int nonText = 0;
    for(String word: words){
        if(!word.matches("^[A-Za-z][a-z]*|[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?|[ .,]|. $")){
            nonText ++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    double percentage = ((double) nonText) / words.length;
    System.out.println(percentage);
    if(percentage > .2){
        return CodeStatus.CODE;
    }
    if(percentage < .1){
        return CodeStatus.TEXT;
    }
    return CodeStatus.INDETERMINATE;
}

enum CodeStatus {
    CODE, TEXT, INDETERMINATE
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
You can try the OpenNLP sentence parser. It returns the n best parses for a sentence. For most English sentences it returns at least one. I believe, that for most code snippets it won't return any and hence you can be quite sure it is not an English sentence.

0.0297029702970297
TEXT
Use this code for parsing:

0.18181818181818182
INDETERMINATE
    // Initialize the sentence detector

0.125
INDETERMINATE
    final SentenceDetectorME sdetector = EasyParserUtils
            .getOpenNLPSentDetector(Constants.SENTENCE_DETECTOR_DATA);

0.6
CODE
    // Initialize the parser

0.16666666666666666
INDETERMINATE
    final Parser parser = EasyParserUtils
            .getOpenNLPParser(Constants.PARSER_DATA_LOC);

0.5333333333333333
CODE
    // Get sentences of the text

0.1
INDETERMINATE
    final String sentences[] = sdetector.sentDetect(essay);

0.38461538461538464
CODE
    // Go through the sentences and parse each

0.07142857142857142
TEXT
    for (final String sentence : sentences) {
        // Parse the sentence, produce only 1 parse
        final Parse[] parses = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 10);
        if (parses.length == 0) {
            // Most probably this is code
        }
        else {
            // An English sentence
        }
    }

0.2537313432835821
CODE
and these are the two helper methods (from EasyParserUtils) used in the code:

0.14814814814814814
INDETERMINATE
public static Parser getOpenNLPParser(final String parserDataURL) {
    try (final InputStream isParser = new FileInputStream(parserDataURL);) {
        // Get model for the parser and initialize it
        final ParserModel parserModel = new ParserModel(isParser);
        return ParserFactory.create(parserModel);
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {

0.3835616438356164
CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.programcreek.com/2015/01/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-english-or-java-code/) is a perfect and safe solution. The basic idea is get all available keywords and special characters first, and then use the set to builder a tokenizer. 
For example, the code line in the question becomes "KEY,SEPARATOR,ID,ASSIGN,NUMBER,SEPARATOR,...". And then we can use simple rules to separate code from English.