# How to check given string is valid java identifier or not?

Tags: java, regex, identifier

I didn't found any algorithms or regular expression or libraries in google for checking given *String* is a valid **Java Identifier** or not. I know the rules of valid declaration for java identifier (or may be help with IDE).

Can somebody support me ***How to check valid java identifer ?***

PS : *please don't be request to describe my efforded codes because I am not too familiar with regular expressions and I know I can write with hard-codes by myself. I am finding better and easy way to check it.*

Comment: First result on google : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205339/regular-expression-matching-fully-qualified-java-classes

Comment: You can check here : [Check whether the given String is a valid identifier according to the Java Language specifications.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/CheckwhetherthegivenStringisavalididentifieraccordingtotheJavaLanguagespecifications.htm)

Comment: @Patrick OP wants to check if string can be used as reference name, not necessary as a type.

Comment: @Patrick do you mean rules of Identifiers are the same with naming classes ?

Comment: @Cataclysm No these rules are different, for instance references can't contain `.` in it while `.` is valid part of type name since it describes its package structure.

Comment: BTW after validating if structure of your string is valid to be variable name you will need to check if it is not [Java reserved keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Comment: The link in your post referes to JPQL identifiers. What are you looking for `Java` or `Java Persistence Query Language` identifiers?

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes , you right ! I am looking for `Java`. So , I am wrong , I think it is oracle official link for Java Identifier.

Comment: If your are using Java 6+, consider `javax.lang.model.SourceVersion` class. It has methods for such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
public class IdentifierTest {

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String arg : args) {
        boolean start = true;
        boolean validIdentifier = true;
        arg.toCharArray() 
        // commenter pointed out my error
        //for(byte b : arg.getBytes()) {
        for(char b : arg.toCharArray()) {
            if(start) {
                validIdentifier = validIdentifier && Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(b);
                start = false;
            } else {
                validIdentifier = validIdentifier && Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(b);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Identifier \""
        + arg + "\" is "
        + (validIdentifier ? "" : "not ")
        + "valid");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What about java `keyword`?