# Rest API + Json response with wrong encode (I think)

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I am developing an automatic signup screen and use restful api to get data based on CEP (postal code) informed by user. ('cep' is the name of the postal code id in brazil).

The problem that I am going through is, apparently, simple to solve.

When I call rest api to get data about address, sometimes the solution works, sometime not.

I am get data passing the url: http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/70040903

My code is:

```
package com.clubee.doggywalker;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by barcat on 6/24/15.
 */
public class cadastro_user extends ActionBarActivity {

//JSON node
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

//url para cadastrar novo usuário
private static String url_cadastraCliente = "http://clubee.com.br/dev/dbDoggyWalker/DoggyWalker_CadastroUsuario_Inserir.php";

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText char_Nome;
EditText char_CEP;
EditText char_Email;
EditText char_Cidade;
EditText char_Estado;
EditText char_Logradouro;
EditText char_Endereco;
EditText char_Bairro;

//barra de progressão
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastro_user);

    char_Nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNome);
    char_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    char_Logradouro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
    char_Endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro2);
    char_Cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
    char_Estado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
    char_Bairro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
    char_CEP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);

    //Criar botão
    Button btnCadastraUsuario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastraUsuario);
    Button btnBuscaCEP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscaEndereco);

    //Criar evento do botão
    btnCadastraUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //abre thread em background
            new CadastraCliente().execute();
        }
    });

    //Criar evento do botão
    btnBuscaCEP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //abre thread em background
            new HttpRequestTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Greeting> {
    @Override
    protected Greeting doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/"+char_CEP.getText();
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class);
            return greeting;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("cadastro_user", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Greeting greeting) {
        TextView greetingLogradouro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
        TextView greetingEndereco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro2);
        TextView greetingBairro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
        TextView greetingCidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
        TextView greetingEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
        TextView greetingCEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
        greetingLogradouro.setText(greeting.getLogradouro());
        greetingEndereco.setText(greeting.getEndereco());
        greetingCidade.setText(greeting.getCidade());
        greetingBairro.setText(greeting.getBairro());
        greetingEstado.setText(greeting.getEstado());
        greetingCEP.setText(greeting.getCep());
    }
}

class CadastraCliente extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(cadastro_user.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cadastrando usuário..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String Nome = char_Nome.getText().toString();
        String Email = char_Email.getText().toString();
        String Endereco = char_Logradouro.getText().toString();
        String TipoLicenca = "Usuario";


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Nome", Nome));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Email", Email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Endereco", Endereco));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_TipoLicenca",TipoLicenca));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_cadastraCliente,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cadastro_user.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * *
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

My DAO is

```
package com.clubee.doggywalker;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

/**
 * Created by barcat on 6/26/15.
 */
public class Greeting {

private String logradouro;
private String cep;
private String bairro;
private String cidade;
private String estado;
private String complemento;
private String unidade;
private String endereco;


public String getBairro() {
    return this.bairro;
}

public String getLogradouro() {
    return this.logradouro;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return this.endereco;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return this.cidade;
}

public String getCep() {
    return this.cep;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return this.estado;
}

public String getComplemento() {
    return this.complemento;
}

public String getUnidade() {
    return this.unidade;
}

}
```

The exception is

> 06-27 19:35:11.696    5845-6029/com.clubee.doggywalker E/cadastro_user﹕ Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "endereço" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "estado", "complemento", "endereco", "cep", "unidade"])
>               at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@2ed70b18).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 70] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereço"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "endereço" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "estado", "complemento", "endereco", "cep", "unidade"])
>               at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@2ed70b18).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 70] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereço"])
>       org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "endereço" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "estado", "complemento", "endereco", "cep", "unidade"])
>               at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@2ed70b18).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 70] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereço"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "endereço" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "estado", "complemento", "endereco", "cep", "unidade"])
>               at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@2ed70b18).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 70] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereço"])
>               at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:126)
>               at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
>               at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:76)
>               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
>               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
>               at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.cadastro_user$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(cadastro_user.java:97)
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.cadastro_user$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(cadastro_user.java:90)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:297)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "endereço" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "estado", "complemento", "endereco", "cep", "unidade"])
>               at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@2ed70b18).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 70] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereço"])
>               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:671)
>               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:771)
>               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
>               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1275)
>   06-27 19:35:11.697    5845-5845/com.clubee.doggywalker D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   06-27 19:35:11.698    5845-5845/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.clubee.doggywalker, PID: 5845
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting.getLogradouro()' on a null object reference
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.cadastro_user$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(cadastro_user.java:114)
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.cadastro_user$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(cadastro_user.java:90)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:641)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:658)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Greeting class you have:

```
private String endereco;
```

but in your data you have

```
"endere\u00e7o": "SBN Quadra 1 Bloco C"
```

which won't match.

from the annotation documentation:

```
 @JsonProperty("firstName")
 public String _first_name;
```

see ([fasterXML annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/))
so you probably need to import the fasterXML annotation and add it to the property

```
@JsonProperty("endere\u00e7o")
private String endereco;
```

I'm not sure how easy this is in android but I assume it should work.
It should then parse.

A 'fun' alternative is to check this stackoverflow question: [unicode variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422655/java-unicode-variable-names)

and use

```
private String endere\u00e7o;
```

but I would only try that out of interest, I wouldn't consider it good practice to use variable names like that ;)

....

or (as I listed in comment) it looks like sometimes you have endereco (with cedille and without) in your input stream.

to ignore any unmappable properties you can put this at the top:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

this will ignore any unmappable properties. Ofcourse check your datastream and check if endereco (without cedille) is always present, then it should be safe to ignore the unicode version.

Comment: I tested with your suggestion, but does not work. 
The error is similar. 
06-27 21:45:37.888  19627-19763/com.clubee.doggywalker E/cadastro_user﹕ Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "endereco" (class com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "cidade", "logradouro", "bairro", "endereço", "estado", "complemento", "cep", "unidade"])
            at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@25382530).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 125] (through reference chain: com.clubee.doggywalker.Greeting["endereco"]);

Comment: I wrote:     @JsonProperty("endere\u00e7o")
    private String endereco;


    public String getEndereco() {
        return this.endereco;
    }

Comment: actually if you look at your data (the link you posted) you'll find that the data contains both

"endereco" and "endereço" whcih probably is why sometimes it works.
could be your datastream sometimes has the property endereço 

try:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
At the top of your class

Comment: Hello joe, I understand the point that you mentioned, but even put the annotation on my DAO source, the problem persists. Another example is when I try to find address from http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/68742730. The app is closed (force close). The exception brings Unrecognized field "estado_info"....but I wrote in my code the piece that follows.     @JsonIgnore
    public String getEstadoInfo() {
        return this.estado_info;
    }

Comment: It works!!!! I review our conversation and re-write some parts of source. Thks a lot, Joe.

Comment: glad it worked.. sorry I dropped off but couldn't think of anything new it could be so was hoping someone else would come with the answer.